# How to set custom page size in mPDF?

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I need some help with mPDF. I want to set up my custom page size (exactly: width 49mm and height 200mm), but I can not find solution. I found mPDF() manual (http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=184) but there are only ready formats like A4, B5 etc. I have to set up my own page format.

Comment: It's written at that link pretty much at the beginning: *"format can be specified either as a pre-defined page size, or as an array of width and height in millimetres (see Example #2 below)."*  - Which part of it was hard to understand (e.g. what is your concrete question?)? Have you problems to decipher *Example #2* or weren't you unable to find it on page? And last but not least: What is your own page format?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is an example that shows how to initiate the page with width and height.

```
// Define a page size/format by array - page will be 190mm wide x 236mm height
$mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8', array(190,236));
```

Comment: is there a limit on page size? example when giving [50,100] it produces an error.