# how to generate a PDF of auto size based on content in PHP

Tags: php, mpdf

I am using php MPDF to generate a PDF files it working fine. But i want to set the height of a pdf page as auto based on content size. Content will come dynamically from DB. Anyone give some idea..

The following is my code

```
$p = 'P';
$mpdf->_setPageSize(array(200, round($mpdf->y)), $p);
```

this output also not correct

Comment: Not sure if this may help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23663501/how-to-set-custom-page-size-in-mpdf

Comment: No, that is for exact size of PDF. But i want auto size based on Content size.

Comment: I think I understand. You want the page to be just tall enough to fit the content, and no taller. So if your content takes up 15cm of vertical space when rendered, you only want the page to be 16cm or something like that. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33022101/mpdf-document-auto-height-pos-printer

Comment: Actually, I now think this answer is most helpful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395455/get-position-of-text-in-mpdf-to-determine-vertical-height-of-html-element

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response. I tried all of this, but i didn't get correct output.  Output coming as either content will split into two page or blank space at bottom of the page. I want output like all content in a single page(if small amount of content or large content) without blank space at bottom.